# How to export LaTeX from Maxima to show in StackOverflow?

Tags: latex, maxima

I export an equation in LaTeX form from Maxima and it gives me

```
$$\arccos \left(\cos \left({{2\,\pi\,f\,t+\varphi}\over{A}}\right)\,A
 -2\,\pi\,f\,t\right)=\varphi$$
```

**How can I get this LaTeX code to show up correctly in StackOverflow?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are interested in MathJax-support; something [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) doesn't have. However, [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) does support MathJax:

[image]